# How can i ignore duplicate values in if statement?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, duplicates

```
var availableMarketGroups = {};

angular.forEach(function (market) {

  if (availableMarketGroups[market.group_id]) { // market.group_id is not sorted id
       availableMarketGroups[market.group_id].count++;
  }  
});
```

market.group_id  -  number ,not sorted, and sometimes its duplicates 
availableMarketGroups[market.group_id].count - its length

Lets see the image for more info.

The numbers of the market groups don't represent real amount of markets.

availableMarketGroups[market.group_id].count show - 15 ,but in real it should be 5 (5 groups) ,because market.group_id is duplicates.

[image]

How can i ignore duplicated market.group_id values in if statement ?

Comment: it seems that everything are unique. update your json and expected outptut

Comment: @Aravind json come from swarm , websocket

Answer (score 0):

```
var availableMarketGroups = {};
var groupsProcessed = [];

angular.forEach(availableMarketGroups, function(marketGroup) {
    if (groupsProcessed.indexOf(marketGroup.group_id) < 0) {
        groupsProcessed.push(marketGroup.group_id);
        availableMarketGroups[market.group_id].count++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for counting unique array elements is to make a function as given below.

```
var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    counts[arr[i]] = 1 + (counts[arr[i]] || 0);
}
```

It will return the unique counts of elements in the array.

Reference : [Count unique elements in array without sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052702/count-unique-elements-in-array-without-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without your data. Generally speaking, you should be able to `reduce` this down to the unique Set of `group_id`s:

```
const uniqueGroups = markets.reduce(function(set, market) {
  if (!set.has(market.group_id)) {
    set.add(market.group_id);
  }
  return set;
}, new Set());

console.log('Unique group count: ', uniqueGroups.size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore:

```
var newObj = _.uniq(market, function(p){ return p.group_id; });
```