# How to find unique number of data-attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="category-item-container">
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Jeans</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">Shirt</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">Hoodie</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">shorts</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Hat</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Hanger</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Boxer</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Tørklæde</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Solbriller</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Bukser</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to find the unique number of `data-group` data-attributes. In this case the number would be 3. I was thinking to turn the list into an array and then loop over the `data-group`, but I am not sure how that could be done, and if it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count unique elements in array without sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052702/count-unique-elements-in-array-without-sorting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Set`, `Array.from` and `document.querySelectorAll` in one line of code

```js
const result = new Set(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li[data-group]'), ({dataset:{group}}) => group)).size;

console.log(`there are ${result} unique groups`);
```

```html
<ul class="category-item-container">
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Jeans</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">Shirt</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">Hoodie</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">shorts</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Hat</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Hanger</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Boxer</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Tørklæde</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Solbriller</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Bukser</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Loop over the elements and add the values of `data-group` to a set. At the end, check the size of the set.

```js
var set = new Set();

document.querySelectorAll('.category-item-container > .category-item').forEach(item => {
  set.add(item.getAttribute('data-group'));
});

console.log(set.size);
```

```html
<ul class="category-item-container">
  <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Jeans</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">Shirt</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">Hoodie</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">shorts</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Hat</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Hanger</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Boxer</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Tørklæde</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Solbriller</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Bukser</li>
  <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cycle every `li` and create an array of unique elements, *e.g.*:

```js
var groups = [];
document.querySelectorAll("ul.category-item-container li").forEach(v => {
  var group = v.getAttribute("data-group");
  if (!groups.includes(group)) {
    groups.push(group);
  }
});
console.log(groups.length);
```

```html
<ul class="category-item-container">
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Jeans</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">Shirt</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">Hoodie</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">shorts</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Hat</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Hanger</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Boxer</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Tørklæde</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="accesories">Solbriller</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="bottoms">Bukser</li>
    <li class="category-item" data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @JaromandaX you're right: I replaced jQuery with VanillaJS 